# CSSTransitionGroup doesn't fade in

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, react-redux

I am quite new to react and I am trying to build a react app. I want a login box to fade in on the page when the login in the navbar is clicked. In my App.js I set up the CSSTransitionGroup like this:

```
<CSSTransitionGroup
    transitionEnterTimeout={500}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
    transitionAppear={true}
    transitionAppearTimeout={500}
    transitionName="fade">
  {loginPopup}
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

The login popup is shown based on state:

```
let loginPopup;

if (display_login) {
  loginPopup = (<LoginPopup key={1} />)
}
```

Now the css I use for the transition looks like this:

```
//fade
.fade-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.fade-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

.fade-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

My problem is...that the fadeout works as intended, but the fadein does not work. It just pops up (no transition).
I also tried using .fade-enter - But I figured that enter was wrong as the LoginPopup component is spawned based on state.

Any ideas why the fade in don't work?

Edit:
This is the gist of the code: https://gist.github.com/xenoxsis/6345eb6897aedf228662ffaf64f65053

Comment: have you tried to set the animation on the initial state ? if not , give a try only on .fade-appear & .fade-leave ...

Comment: @GCyrillus Yeah I tried that with an earlier thing, it was the same thing...Then I found a JSfiddle that did it this way...

Comment: a simple example ;) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGJRNv , can you maybe set a full snippet that demonstrate yur issue ?

Comment: @GCyrillus https://gist.github.com/xenoxsis/6345eb6897aedf228662ffaf64f65053

This is every file that has something to do with the transitions :)

Comment: App.js contains the CSSTransitionGroupElement, as well as the state dependent LoginPopup

LoginMenuItem: The onclick event on the link invokes the action to toggle the visibility of the <LoginPopup />

Comment: Try adding a `component` property to your `CSSTransitionGroup` `component="div"`